# Phantom-Evasion OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, subprocess

I face this error when I open Phantom-Evasion in Kali Linux:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./phantom-evasion.py", line 716, in <module>
    Phantom_lib.xmr_miner()
  File "Setup/Phantom_lib.py", line 775, in xmr_miner
    subprocess.call(['tmux','send-keys','-t','phantom-miner','\"\x03\"','C-m'], stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb'), stderr=open(os.devnull,'wb'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
```

Comment: Where is your code, enviroment, packages version, python version? StackOverflow users can't read in minds yet.

Comment: What happens when you run the command ("`tmux send-keys....`") manually from the console.

Comment: Gino Mempin thanks for your help and the solution is to install tmux using  sudo apt-get install tmux